# Смысл private полей и методов

Tags: ооп

Здравствуйте.

Объясните, пожалуйста, смысловое назначение закрытых полей и методов в классах.

Как рассуждаю я: смысл ООП, помимо прочего, в возможности расширять классы. Соответственно, когда я описываю класс, то, помня также о необходимости инкапсулировать внутренние механизмы, использую модификатор protected. В таком случаи, у класса-наследника будет полностью работающий функционал предка, который можно модифицировать/расширять.

А если я использую private, то я не хочу, чтобы даже наследники имели доступ к некоторым полям и/или методам. Раз наследник сможет получить только предка-инвалида (если еще, к тому же, закрыть какое-нибудь поле, но сделать защищенным метод, который это поле использует), то, быть может, проще объявить класс final, чтобы никто не мог класс наследовать?

Сейчас же я встречаю большое количество классов, в которых б**о**льшая часть функционала - закрыта. Какой в этом смысл?

Прошу прощения за некую сумбурность мыслей.

Comment: Добавлю лепту от себя: почитайте про аксессоры `get` и `set` и выгоду от их применения в свете инкапсуляции. Сравните примеры "без" применения и "с".

Answer (score 4):

Поясню на примере смысл приватных методов. Берем машину - ну скажем для определенности Audi. Смотрим на нее с точки зрения ООП. И так что мы видим:

1. `public` методы: завести, включить передачу, нажать на газ/тормоз и проч.
2. `protected` методы: управление магнитолой, приборами и проч. которые общие для всех моделей Audi. Правда, как и полагается в старших моделях Audi производитель может и реально делает `Override` некоторых методов родительского класса.
3. `private` методы: настройка системы распределения зажигания, тюнинг клапанов и проч. проч. хитрые способы, куда обычному юзеры с шаловливыми ручками лезть не стоит.

**P.S.** Конечно, всегда находятся особенно хитро*опые товарищи, которые начинают лезть в приватные методы с целью, скажем чип-тюнинга машины. Для Java аналогом таких способов является доступ к закрытым методам с помощью рефлексии.

Comment: ... а если взять отечественный автопром ...

Answer (score 3):

1. `final` - когда тебе не надо изменять
       значение.
2. `private final` - когда тебе не надо
       изменять значение и не надо что бы
       его о нем знал кто-то другой
3. `private` - когда надо изменять
       значение, но только в текущем классе

Предположим в классе-родителе ты создал переменную "а", она публичная и используется в каком-то методе. Потом ты создал дочерний класс и вызываешь этот метод, предположим вывод чисел от 0 до 10, причем перед этим ты вызвал переменную "а" и присвоил эй другое значение, будет уже ошибка, над которой надо будет разбираться, особенно если родительский класс писал не ты.

Comment: Вопрос, может быть от незнания, но какой смысл объявлять ``private`` метод еще и ``final``?

Comment: делать private метод final -ом нету некого смысла, наоборот(в смысле только final) - есть в случае, если хочешь разрешать доступ к методу, но запретить его переопределять.

Comment: @Gorets, смысл есть. Для final-методов позднее связывание не нужно, они могут быть вызваны напрямую.

Comment: смысла НЕТ, приват метод закрыт и финал модификатор там бесполезный, вопрос оптимизации оооочень спорный так как JVM умнее чем кажется и сама проводит оптимизацию. Может ты путаешь со static? Кого ты на прямую вызывать собрался?

Comment: Со static я ничего не путаю, но не понимаю, откуда у нас взялась JVM?

Comment: private final void ToBeOrNotToBe() {};

зачем final?

Answer (score 1):

Смысл private методов и переменных, например, в том, чтобы разработчик наследуемых классов не лез в родительские реализации базового функционала.

Answer (score 1):

Для приватной области (**private**) присущи такие вещи как:

1. Сокрытия методов родительского класса
2. Сокрытие реализации класса(начинки), чтоб программисты в этот алгоритм не вникали (работает правильно и хорошо зачем трогать)

Все выше написанное относится к такому понятию ООП как **инкапсуляция**.

Класс должен предоставлять только интерфейс работы с ним. а это и есть публичная область (**public**)

Если производному классу от него нужен доступ к "начинки класса" применяется спецификатор **protected**

Answer (score -1):

Смысл в том, что родительский класс, кроме возможности расширения, может содержать *свой собственный автомат*, реализация которого для *обеспечения целостности* закрыта **private**.

Если это не закрытый автомат, родитель не имеет своих собственных, сепаратных *состояний*, которые необходимо *инкапсулировать*, то особого смысла в `private` действительно нет.

Нужно это практически или нет в каждом конкретном случае вопрос отдельный. Но ради универсальности такая возможность поддерживается.

Comment: Причем здесь вообще *конечные автоматы*?

Comment: Узнаю почерк *а ля технический ВУЗ* - там бывает целый выводок преподов повернутых на конечных автоматах они и корёжат сознание молодняка своими идеями.

Comment: Всё просто. И технические ВУЗы тут не причём. 

Если это не закрытый _автомат_, родительский класс не имеет своих собственных, сепаратных _состояний_, которые необходимо _инкапсулировать_, особого смысла в __private__ действительно нет никакого.

Comment: Остальные же ответы в сущности сводятся к копированию догм из учебников: "так есть, потому, что так есть, вот тебе пример". Я попытался объяснить, _почему_ так есть.